# How to show Javascript Data in input field

Tags: laravel

How can I show JavaScript data in a form field?

```js
var amzntheURL = "https://www.alphavantage.co/query?function=GLOBAL_QUOTE&symbol=AMZN&apikey=demo";

$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#amznstockIndicator").show();
  doAjax(amzntheURL);

  $('.ajaxtrigger').click(function() {
    $("#amznstockIndicator").show();
    doAjax(amzntheURL);
    return false;
  });

  function amznnumberWithCommas(x) {
    return x.toString().replace(/\B(?=(?:\d{3})+(?!\d))/g, ",");
  }

  function doAjax(url) {
    $.ajax({
      url: url,
      dataType: 'json',
      contentType: "application/json",
      success: function(data) {

        var amznsymbol = data['Global Quote']['01. symbol']        
        var amznlastTradePriceOnly = data['Global Quote']['05. price']
        var amznlastVolume = data['Global Quote']['06. volume']
        var amznchangep = data['Global Quote']['10. change percent']

        $('#DataID').html(amznlastTradePriceOnly);        
        $("#amznstockIndicator").hide();        
      }
    });
  }
  
  
});
```

```html
<div>
<span id="DataID"></span>
</div>

<form role="form" action="{{url('user/name')}}" method="post">
<div class="form-group mb-3">
<div class="input-group input-group-merge input-group-alternative">
<div class="input-group-prepend">
<span class="input-group-text"> USD</span>
</div>
<input type="number" step="any" class="form-control" placeholder="" name="amount" required>
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" value="AMZN" name="symbol">
<input type="hidden" class="form-control" id="DataID" name="price">
</div>
</div>
<div class="text-center">
<button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary my-4">Purchase</button>
<h4><span id="amznstock_changp"></span></h4>
</div>
</form>
```

When I type the code then showing data on-page, it's working fine, but I want the same data show on the form field. **If any confusion please let me know, then I will change the text.**

Comment: What's happen with `$('#DataID').text(amznlastTradePriceOnly);` or `$('#DataID').html(data.amznlastTradePriceOnly);`?

Comment: @STA nothing happens, just I need to show some data of <span id="DataID"></span>
 on the input value.

Comment: any other option get data for the post in the database without inpute with javascript data "<span id="DataID"></span>"

Comment: or anyone please tell me that how I post alpha vantage API data to the database table automatically by specifying a time.